# is it possible search by metadata in box api and return file and metadata together?

Tags: box-api, boxapiv2

I'm using a metadata search in box api:

https://api.box.com/2.0/search?mdfilters=

The search is ok, but I'm passing metadata for search, but after return I receive only file information, not any metadata from files. Is it possible search by metadata in box api and return file and metadata together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does not appear possible. Your best option is to [request all file metadata](https://developer.box.com/v2.0/reference#get-all-metadata) using the file ID returned in the search result. If you get multiple search results consider sending the metadata requests in parallel (up to ~10 requests/user/sec) to speed things up.